# Deploying rails app on nginx: no index.html file in app's public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I'm a beginner in rails.
I was trying to deploy an app from github to my digital ocean account. 
The app is not mine, I just wanted to deploy it, modify and learn by messing around.

I installed passenger and nginx.

As far as I understand, I have to add a server code block in nginx.conf, that looks something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /app/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_min_instances 1;      # <--- added
}
```

Now, the problem is that the public folder doesn't contain the index.html file

The routes.rb file has the following content for root

```
root :to => "home#index",
  :protocol => (Rails.application.config.force_ssl ? "https://" : "http://"),
  :as => "root"
```

Can anyone help how to resolve this?

Comment: Just create it there?

Comment: Unclear how this is related to nginx. You should just be able to create an `index` method in your `HomeController`.

Comment: This should work as long as your Rails application public directory is /app/public.  There is no need for an `index.html` file in Rails.  The Rails routing mechanism handles routing requests to the proper controller and action.

Comment: Serving file public/index.html bypasses Rails which you probably try to avoid by using passenger and make Rails does it job